# Break down a sentence into few simple sentences

Tags: run-on-sentences

I am having the following construction.

> In regularization of outer-boundaries, outer-boundary line segments
>   fitted from irregularly distributed contour points as described by
>   Horde and Susan (2012) are rectified by rotating their mid-points
>   until orthogonality or parallelism is met with respect to the
>   identified direction.

But, I have been advised to break them in to simple sentences.

***Now, my question is what would be the most beautiful way to represent whole idea by few simple sentences.***

Here is my try. But I feel my way is not the best way and looking for some advanced way.

> In regularization of outer-boundaries, boundary line segments can be
>   first fitted from irregularly distributed contour points as described
>   by Horde and Susan (2012).
>
> The fitted line segments can then be rectified by rotating their
>   mid-points until orthogonality or parallelism is met with respect to
>   the identified direction.

Comment: *Have* in this sense is stative and can't appear on the progressive construction *\*am having*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentences look fine to me. One possible way to make the reading smoother is to move the reference to the front or the back. For example,

> As described by Horde and Susan (2012), in regularization of outer-boundaries, boundary line segments can be first fitted from irregularly distributed contour points, and then rectified by rotating their mid-points until orthogonality or parallelism is met with respect to the identified direction.

Here is another alternative,

> As described by Horde and Susan (2012), in regularization of outer-boundaries, boundary line segments can be first fitted from irregularly distributed contour points. They can then be rectified by rotating their mid-points until orthogonality or parallelism is met with respect to the identified direction.

Comment: i like your second option. I think I should avoid can be as in my original sentence it is not there. So, If I use is/are (what is the good verb for these two) instead of can be, do you think the meaning or readability is deviate? So, If I say: As described by Horde and Susan (2012), in regularization of outer-boundaries, boundary line segments *are* first fitted from irregularly distributed contour points. They *are then* rectified by rotating their mid-points until orthogonality or parallelism **are ** met with respect to the identified direction.

Comment: You can. I believe you can do that in the other alternative (the first one) too.

Comment: my wordprocessor gave me ... orthogonality or parallelism are met with.... instead of is.. Do you think ARE is correct?

Comment: I meant *are fitted* and *are then rectified*. As for the verb *met*, it should be *until orthogonality or parallelism is met*. We have two abstract uncountable nouns *orthogonality* and *parallelism*, linked with *or*, so *is* is the correct usage.