# Reformulating a sentence with a more clear idea

Tags: conjunctions, relative-pronouns, coordination

In my technical paper, I have written as follows.

> The strategy is used to fix outer-boundaries is useful for maintaining
>   symmetries and alignments of boundaries.

But, I have been asked to reformulated this sentence. I am confused now what is the wrong with this... Doesn't this give a clear literacy?

So, If I write like this

> The strategy used to fix outer-boundaries is useful for maintaining
>   ***gutter*** symmetries and ***as well as*** alignments of ***adjacent*** boundaries.

However, please suggest your way because I want to learn how this can be improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the first place, you have two main verbs:

   > The strategy is used to...
   >   [The strategy ...] is useful for...

   You may fix this by 'conjoining' them with an *and*

   > The strategy is used to ... **and** is useful for...

   But I suspect what you mean is that “the strategy **which**  is used to &c is useful”.  This may be reduced to “the strategy used to fix outer boundaries is useful for...”— as you do in your rewrite.
2. There is an ambiguity in the last part of the sentence: it is not clear whether the phrase *of boundaries* modifies both *symmetries* and *alignments* or only *alignments*. It appears from your rewrite that it is supposed to modify only *alignments*; I would rewrite this as

   > ... for maintaining symmetries and boundary alignments.

   If *boundary* were intended to modify both, I would make this explicit:

   > ... for maintaining boundary symmetries and boundary alignments.

   This may appear a little wordy; but in technical writing you cannot be too precise. The Adamantine Law is that in written discourse, “Anything which *can* be misunderstood *will* be misunderstood.”
3. As for your rewrite: I don’t know enough about your topic to judge whether the more detailed specification with *gutter* and *adjacent* is necessary; that is between you and your thesis supervisor or publisher. But the use of *as well as* is doubly faulty:

   - *X and as well as Y* is not an idiomatic construction. You may say “X and Y” or “X as well as Y” or “X, and Y as well”.
   - *X as well as Y* is **not** equivalent to *X and Y*: it does not coordinate the two entities X and Y, it adds a parenthetical observation about Y.  Use *A is X as well as Y* only when you have previously stated that *A is Y*, and you wish to remind the reader of that fact—for instance, if you want to make it clear that saying *A is X* does not contradict or exclude A being Y.
4. *Outer-boundaries*, with a hyphen, is not conventional English. Ordinarily an adjective is assumed to attach to and modify the following noun, so there is no need for a hyphen. The hyphen is need only when the modified noun itself serves as a modifier, as in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/15773/32) of yours, where the hyphen in “outer-boundary line segments” makes it clear that *outer* modifies only *boundary*, not *line segments*.